# Rules and regulations of all airlines in one site for consumers to compare

Tags: web-crawling, products, public-transport

There are lot of rules and regulations that airlines have. At the same time, due to business dynamics and other changes in the environment, the rules get changed. It would be useful if there is a site where information from all the airlines were available under one roof and is parsed so people could compare on some functionalities without getting dodged by the length of reading material.

It would be useful to two kinds of people.

a. Newbie travelers or people trying to figure out the labyrinth of rules and regulations.

b. Researchers who research trends about airlines and markets surrounding them.

See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/70781/is-there-a-site-where-pdfs-of-all-airlines-related-to-passenger-rules-regulation/70782?noredirect=1#comment152300_70782 related to it.